# PHP button onclick self.location.href

Tags: php

I would like to create a button with the option to redirect to a page:

I try with :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="self.location.href='update.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['Auth']['id'];?>'">)Update</button>
```

But no result.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your anchor tag `<a>` act as button using `role='button'` property. Pass your required `URL` in `href`.

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" href="update.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['Auth']['id'];?>">
  Update
</a>
```